# selectOneListbox from another form is not being selected for the first time

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ajax4jsf, selectonemenu

I have two instances of **selectOneListbox** which reference to the same property in a managed bean. Both lists belong to different forms.

When after selecting position in one of the lists, I choose the one in another, it is not getting selected, **only for the first time**; further selections are all fine.

Please advice how to solve the problem.

**JSF**

```
    <h:form>
            <ul style="list-style: none">
                <li>
                    <h:selectOneListbox size="1" value="#{adminController.model}" > 
                        <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="@all"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{adminController.gtSelectItem()}" var="p" itemValue="${p.name}" itemLabel="${p.name}"/>
                    </h:selectOneListbox>     
                </li>    
            </ul>
        </h:form>
        <h:form>
            <ul>
                <li>  
                    <h:selectOneListbox size="1" value="#{adminController.model}" > 
                        <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="@all"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{adminController.gtSelectItem()}" var="p" itemValue="${p.name}" itemLabel="${p.name}"/>
                    </h:selectOneListbox>     
                </li>   
                <h:commandButton value="Print">
                    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{adminController.printAjax()}"/>
                </h:commandButton>
            </ul>

        </h:form>
    </div>
```

**Managed Bean property**

```
public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}
```

**SelectItems**

```
public ArrayList<Product> gtSelectItem() {
    ArrayList<Product> als = new ArrayList<>(pc.getProductList());
    return als;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to have two components reference the same property? Perhaps there is another way that will give you what you need. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi, its a part of a control panel. I have several forms allowing to add, remove and edit products. It is handy to have all fields immediately filled with data, regardless from which option list the product was chosen. When I nest these selectOneListboxes inside of a single form, all works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many things to solve there. First of all, **getter and setter prefixes are not written** when using EL. Just use `value="#{adminController.selectItem}"` when you've a property to read/write. Your provided code is mistyped and `ul` and `li` tags are not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Appart from that, don't use `render="@all"`. **It's generally considered a bad practice to render the whole page again using ajax**. To do that, just perform an standard POST request. In your case, you can render only the other form, or even better, the component you're particularly interested in.

Here you've a tested [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) about your issue, which works ;-)

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Test page</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form1">
        <h:selectOneListbox size="1" value="#{adminController.model}">
            <f:ajax event="valueChange" render=":form2" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{adminController.selectItem}" var="p"
                itemValue="${p.name}" itemLabel="${p.name}" />
        </h:selectOneListbox>

    </h:form>
    <h:form id="form2">
        <h:selectOneListbox size="1" value="#{adminController.model}">
            <f:ajax event="valueChange" render=":form1" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{adminController.selectItem}" var="p"
                itemValue="${p.name}" itemLabel="${p.name}" />
        </h:selectOneListbox>
        <h:commandButton value="Print">
            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{adminController.printAjax}" />
        </h:commandButton>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AdminController implements Serializable {

    public AdminController() {
        System.out.println("Bean created");
    }

    public class Product {

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        String name;

        public Product(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

    String model;

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public List<Product> getSelectItem() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Product("Prod1"), new Product("prod2"));
    }

    public void printAjax() {
        System.out.println("Printing " + model);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you and is there a resource with "best practices for ajax for JSF?"

Comment: You can have a look though online tutorials or look here for @BalusC answers, they are always so useful. If the answer was helpful for you, mark the thread as answered (✓ mark in the left side of the answer).